# Problem in navigation from child fragment to bottom nav fragment

Tags: kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a bottom nav bar and im using navigation components to navigate. I have 4 fragments in bottom nav and one fragment opens from the recyclerview of fragment A:
here is the sequence of navigate

1. Fragment A to Fragment B (not a bottom nav fragment)
2. Fragment B to Fragment C (a bottom nav fragment)
3. Fragment C to Fragment A ( Hereis the problem the Fragment B is still showing and there is no click shown on Fragment A)

I have tried useing popUpto or popUpinclusive in Fragment B but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized that its the default behavior of nav controller and I just have to pop the fragment from back stack manually.